# generating a unique no for coupon code 6 to 8 digit for any no of coupon

Tags: php

```
for($i=0,$ii=1;$i<$_POST['no_of_coupon']; $ii++) {
    $unique_code=uniqid();
    $category_unique_code = substr($unique_code,rand(0,strlen($unique_code) - 6),6);
    $i++;
    echo $category_unique_code;
}
```

**`$_POST['no_of_coupon']` is the no . For eg. if user want  1 lakh coupon code or more i.e.  `$_POST['no_of_coupon']`, all the code is inserted into the the database and the code is unique but I have tried above method ,  but its not unique then i tried another method**

```
function gen_random($length=32)
{
    $final_rand='';
    for($i=0;$i< $length;$i++)
    {
        $final_rand .= rand(0,9);
    }
    return $final_rand;
}
for($i=0,$ii=1;$i<$_POST['no_of_coupon']; $ii++) {
            $unique_code=gen_random(6);
            $category_unique_code = substr($unique_code,rand(0,strlen($unique_code) - 6),6);
            $i++;
            echo $category_unique_code;
}
```

This method is also not generating unique coupon code , I just need 6 to 8 digit unique no So somebody have any idea to generate unique no , please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will generate an 8 digit unique coupon code:

```
function getUniqueCouponCode ()
{
    $filename = 'number.txt';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $actual_number = file_get_contents($filename);
    } else {
        $actual_number = 1;
    }
    file_put_contents($filename, $actual_number + 1);
    return str_pad($actual_number, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Try this to create a 6 or 8 digit unique no:
    <?php 
        $date=date('y-m-dh:i:s'); 
        echo substr(md5($date),0,6);
    ?>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't create a 6 or 8 digit unique no. `md5()` function returns the hash as a 32-character hexadecimal number, so it can return letters also.